# Error when running getModisWS command from MODIS package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run the `getModisWS` command from the MODIS package and am getting an error.

```
b <- getModisWS(40, -110, "MOD13Q1", "250m_16_days_NDVI", "A2000049", "A2000097", "1", "1")
```

Error:

```
"Error occurred in the HTTP request:  Above-Below km subset size has to be an integer value NA"
```

This is the example from the package documentation, I have not been able to get it to work by tinkering with the above-below km options.  I am running Mac OS v. 10.6.8 and R v. 2.15.1.  Any help would be appreciated.